# Simplest set that requires Replacement but cannot be achieved using Power-Set

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking for a simple example to the use of the Replacement axiom to conclude that a certain class is a set. The simplest examples I think of can be proven also using the Power-Set Axiom, e.g the set $\{\{x\}\mid x\in A\}$ for some set $A$, and $A/E$ for an equivalence relation $E$ on a set $A$.

The first example which seem to really require Replacement, while Power-set is not enough, is e.g. $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}...\}$, but it seems that to prove this I must use a theorem  on definition by recursions.

A similar example appears in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150467/63762) but it seems that the proof is essentially going over the proof of the recursion theorem in the very specific case appearing there.

Is there a simpler example which doesn't require such a theorem?

(I don't need a *proof* that Replacement is necessary while Power-set is not enough.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused - your second-to-last line suggests you want an example with a simpler proof, but your last sentence suggests you don't care about the proof?

Comment: I want a simple proof using replacement that some class is a set, one that e.g. doesn't even invoke the recursion theorem. I want that the use of replacement can't be replaced by a use of power-set, but I don't need a simple proof of this fact.

Comment: Since [the recursion theorem is equivalent to replacement](http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/), I think you will never be able to find a perfectly satisfying example, then.

Comment: Oh, I did not know/remember that!

Comment: Existence of $\{\{x\}:x\in A\}$  is provable in ZF minus Power, minus Foundation, minus Infinity: The Pairing Axiom and Extensionality imply that $\{x\}$ exists uniquely whenever  whenever $x$ exists. And $\forall A\;\forall x\in A \;\exists!y \;(y=\{x\})$ is an instance of a "Replacement" condition. So $\forall A\;\exists B\;\forall x\in A \;(\{x\}\in B)$. By Comprehension, $\forall A \;\forall B\;\exists C=\{b\in B: \exists x\in A (b=\{x\}\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, but it can also be proven with power-set and without replacement. I'm looking for something that cannot be proved using power-set without replacement

Comment: I dk how $\{\{x\}:x\in A\}$ can be shown to exist without Replacement and without Power.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet i wrote without replacement and **with** power-set

Comment: (with separation of course)

Comment: Sorry about that..............

Answer (score 4):

The **class of countable ordinals** constitutes such an example.

Consider the following formula:

> Let $\varphi(x, y)$ be the formula "**EITHER** $x$ is a linear ordering with domain $\subseteq\omega$, $y$ is an ordinal, and there is an order-preserving bijection between $x$ and $y$, **OR** $x$ is a linear ordering with domain $\subseteq\omega$, $y=0$, and there is no ordinal with an order-preserving bijection to $x$."

Now we let $A$ be the class of ordinals $y$ such that for some linear ordering $x$ with domain $\subseteq \omega$ there is an order-presreving bijection from $x$ to $y$.

- Using replacement, $A$ is a set: apply replacement to the formula $\varphi$ with the "starting set" being the set $S$ of linear orderings with domain $\subseteq\omega$.
- Without replacement, we cannot show that $A$ is a set: in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ we have $A=Ord$.

---

NOTE: This is an example of a more general recipe: given an attempt to build an object $\mathfrak{O}$ by recursion, we can define the class $\mathcal{C}$ of "partial approximations" which actually exist. If $\mathfrak{O}$ represents a failure of replacement, $\mathcal{C}$ will not be a set. Conversely, the approach above lets us show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a set without doing any recursion: we basically consider the map sending a "stage" in the recursion to the corresponding partial object if it exists and to $0$ (or some other fixed set) otherwise. So this represents a uniform way to eliminate the use of recursion. However, ultimately *this is exactly the proof of the recursion theorem* so in general situations this won't be satisfying to you. This reflects the fact that [replacement is in fact equivalent to recursion](http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/), so in a precise sense you can never find a perfectly satisfying example.

Comment: Sorry, this was not my intention, see my reply to your comment above.

Comment: @UrYa'ar I've added an example you may find preferable.

Comment: @UrYa'ar Does the new example feel more in line with what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I like this example, but I'm looking for something even simpler, that doesn't even require one to know what is a well order or an ordinal. An example that can be given almost immediately after phrasing the axioms. Since as you say recursion is inevitable, then the example I mentioned in the question or the ones   Asaf seem simplest in that sense.

Comment: Although I agree that once you have the notions of well order and ordinal your example is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that $V_\omega$ is the simplest. If you want something slightly less on the nose, $\mathcal P^\omega(\Bbb N)$.

Both can be easily described to students without fussing all that much about ordinals.

Comment: I also thought about these before Noah's answer, and discarded them since they need recursion, but since recursion is essentially inevitable, I need to see which one can be most easily defined using a formula stating the existence of approximations.

Comment: Both are equally simple. You can show them for one, and ask them to prove home for the other. Because $V_\omega$ is $\mathcal P^\omega(\varnothing)$.

Comment: Yes indeed. Now I'm trying to formulate the proof for $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}...\}$ which is also essentially the same. And even "simpler" in some sense.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. I should be more or less all the same.

Comment: Well yea the proof would be the same. The only sense it's "simpler" is that it uses weaker notions than power set.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

Since by Noah Schweber's answer, the recursion theorem can't really be avoided, I give an explicit definition which I hope is simplest, in the sense that it doesn't require notions such as well-order or ordinal, and doesn't use the full recursion theorem, but essentially follows it's proof in a very specific case. So it can be given after one learns the axioms and what are functions. This also incorporates Asaf Karagila's answer.

Given some function $G:A\to A$ and $a\in A$ (e.g. $G(x)=\{x\}$ or $G(x)=\mathcal{P}(x)$) define $\varphi(x,y)$ to be the formula:
$$x\in\mathbb{N}\land\exists f \Big[f\,\mathrm{is\,a\,function\,}\land Dom\left(f\right)=\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n\leq x\right\} \land y=f\left(x\right)\land \\
  \land f\left(0\right)=a\land\forall z\in\mathbb{N}\left(z<x\to f\left(z+1\right)=G( f\left(z\right)\ \right)\Big]
$$
Then one has to prove that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a unique such $f$, so that $F=\{<x,y>\mid \varphi(x,y)\}$ is a well-defined function satisfying $F(n)=G^n(a)$, so applying replacement gives the set
$ \{G^n(a)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\} $, which may e.g. be $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}...\}$.