# Existence of a closure of a subset

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $M$ be a set and $\circ$ an operation defined on subsets of $M$ in the following way:

1. $A \circ B \subseteq M$ for any $A \subseteq M$ and $B \subseteq M$;
2. If $A' \subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$, then $A' \circ B' \subseteq A \circ B$.

Let us say a subset $C$ of $M$ is *closed* under $\circ$ if $C \circ C \subseteq C$.

Clearly, $M$ is closed under $\circ$.

Let us say a subset $C$ is a *closure* of a subset $S$ of $M$ if:

1. $C$ is closed under $\circ$ and $S \subseteq C$;
2. If $S \subseteq C' \subseteq C$ for a subset $C'$ closed under $\circ$, then $C' = C$.

Clearly, $M$ is a closure of itself.

It is easy to show that a closure of a subset $S$ of $M$, if exists, is unique:

- Assuming $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two closures of $S$;
- Denoting $C$ = $C_1 \cap C_2$;
- $C \subseteq C_1$, therefore $C \circ C \subseteq C_1 \circ C_1 \subseteq C_1$;
- $C \subseteq C_2$, therefore $C \circ C \subseteq C_2 \circ C_2 \subseteq C_2$;
- $C \circ C \subseteq C_1$ and $C \circ C \subseteq C_2$, therefore $C \circ C \subseteq C_1 \cap C_2$;
- $C \circ C \subseteq C$, therefore $C$ is closed under $\circ$;
- $C$ is closed under $\circ$, $S \subseteq C \subseteq C_1$, therefore $C = C_1$;
- $C$ is closed under $\circ$, $S \subseteq C \subseteq C_2$, therefore $C = C_2$.

But how can we prove that the closure exists for any subset of $M$?

If it is not true, what could be an additional requirement on $\circ$ to guarantee existence of the closure?

Comment: You already proved it. First, for any subset $S\subseteq M$, There exist at least one closed superset ($M$ is closed). Now consider $C$ the intersection of all the closed supersets of $S$. Arguing as you did, you can see $C$ is a closed superset of $S$.

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández Thank you. Would you like to create an answer?

Comment: Let me write it down with a bit more detail.

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández Can this be used to prove the transitive closure theorem?

Comment: Can you link me somewhere to look at the precise statement of that theorem? I will check it

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150467/427611

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2284992/427611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S\subseteq M$ be arbitrary. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all closed supersets of $S$. We know that $M\in\mathcal{A}$ so $\mathcal{A}\neq \emptyset$. Let us consider $C=\bigcap \mathcal{A}$.

First we will check that $C$ is a closed superset of $S$. Arguing as you did, for any $K\in \mathcal{A}$

- $C\subseteq K$, therefore $C\circ C\subseteq K\circ K \subseteq K$.

As $K$ was arbitrary this means $C\circ C\subseteq C$ and hence $C$ is a closed superset of $S$. By construction $C$ is also the smallest such set and hence the closure of $S$.

Comment: It looks like the answer proves both existence and uniqueness, correct?

Comment: @AlexC Yes, uniqueness can be deduced by construction of $C$. For the existence of the transitive closure of a set  you have to be careful, my proof relies in $M$ being closed and also a set. In the theorem your $M$ is now the class of all sets, and I am not sure this kind of argument will work.